# Запуск 1 экземпляра программы на каждого пользователя

Tags: c#, windows

Представим терминал, на нем сидит n-ое кол-во пользователей.
Как сделать так, что бы каждый пользователь мог запустить 1 экземпляр программы?

Видел решение контроля этого для одного пользователя системы через создание Mutex с определенным именем и проверкой его существования. Ну, вроде, это работать не будет, так как Mutex-это, по идее, глобальный объект ОС.

Видел решение, через проверку существующих экземпляров и просмотр логина пользователя. Однако, для этого, по идее, нужны спец. права. Так как в том же Task Manager нельзя без спец. прав посмотреть процессы других юзеров в системе.

Comment: А кто мешает в имя мутекса положить id пользователя

Comment: Хм... А это в теории должно работать.

Comment: Или разделяемую память, хранящую список подключенных пользователей c pid процессов. при запуске если пользватель в списке смотреть используется ли данный pid. на это прав должно хватать так как ищем pid процесса запущенного тем же пользователем

Comment: А разделяемая память разве шарится между сеансами?

Comment: В windows не знаю. По логике такой ресурс как разделяемая память должен быть глобальным на ОС

Comment: Или вообще файлы на диске опять же с id пользователя в названии и блокировкой которую удерживает процесс

Answer (score 0):

> Видел решение, через проверку существующих экземпляров и просмотр логина пользователя. Однако, для этого, по идее, нужны спец. права.

Нет. Твоя задача тать возможность запускать одну программу на одного юзера. Проверку что там у других юзеров делать вообще не нужно! И спецправ иметь не нужно, соответственно. А для чего? В рамках одного инстанса программы нужно знать только про другие инстансы программы под конкретным данным юзером. Другие пользователи тебя колыхать не должны вообще, если так подумать :)

---

И да, дополнительное гугление по ключевикам

> c# app instance "per user"

показало, что прекрасным способом для поставленной задачи является создание локального мьютекса ( `"Local\"` ). Но может быть возможность запуска нескольких сессий одного юзера. На серверах например. И тогда может вылезти проблемка.

Но если хочется быть на 100% уверенным в том, что только 1 инстанс на юзера, то нужно использовать `"Global\"` + UserDomainName + UserName + гуид.

```
string globalMutexName = string.Format(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    "Global\\AppName~{0}~{1}~some-unique-guid",
    Environment.UserDomainName,
    Environment.UserName);

_machineLocalAppInstanceMutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, globalMutexName, out mutexIsNew);

if (!mutexIsNew)
{
    Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Типа по имени определяется будет ли мьютекс глобальным или локальным?

Comment: `"On a server that is running Terminal Services, a named system mutex can have two levels of visibility. If its name begins with the prefix "Global\", the mutex is visible in all terminal server sessions. If its name begins with the prefix "Local\", the mutex is visible only in the terminal server session where it was created................ "Global\" and "Local\" describe the scope of the mutex name relative to terminal server sessions, not relative to processes."`  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: и кривой машинный перевод от майкрсофта: http://prntscr.com/m7s8xw в полной мере доступный по https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netframework-4.7.2